# Excel need to color based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2 columns, one is for currency list and another contains some name with country and curreny (see the attached screenshot). I need to color rows depending if the currency and country will match.

[image]

Comment: Use conditional formatting with a formula like `= $C2 = RIGHT($B2,3)`

Comment: Sorry, just noticed there are 4-letter ones as well, small update to the formula would be `= $C2 = RIGHT($B2, LEN($C2))`

Comment: is this possible to same for country wise , need to mark those based on country, example i have a country name CANADA in "column  C" and "Column B" i have a name called "000-1150 Corporate BluJay-Global Support - Canada - CAD" then need to take this country..      Overall summary (if country matched both column then took.

Comment: See [this link about search/find](https://exceljet.net/formulas/cell-contains-specific-text) for that.